# How to set a shell variable in ruby script?

Tags: ruby, shell

Hi this is my following code. I need to get the value through shell script which is assigned in ruby script.

```
#!/bin/bash

ruby <<EOM
    system <<-CMD
        export VARNAME=123
    CMD
EOM
echo "------"
echo ${VARNAME}
```

it is printing output as

```
------
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. A child process inherits its parent's environment, but cannot modify it.